# infinite scrolling not reloading jquery scripts such as facebook and twitter

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, infinite

im using a jquery plugin for infinite scrolling, and its working perfectly except for the client side scripts that need to run.

my infinite scrolling script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.infinite-container').waypoint('infinite', {
      container: 'auto',
      items: '.infinite-item',
      more: '.infinite-more-link',
      offset: 'bottom-in-view',
      loadingClass: 'infinite-loading',
      onBeforePageLoad: $.noop,
      onAfterPageLoad: $.noop
    });
</script>
```

what the waypoints website says is that onAfterPageLoad:

> A function to execute after new page items have been loaded and
>   appended to the container.

```
onAfterPageLoad:
```

my key issue is that my twitter and facebook buttons aren't loading. all i can see is the word "twitter" and facebook buttons dont show up at all. But on the initial page they load no problem.

also i have a sticky element thats not working as well. it works on the initial page load but not on the infinite scrolling page load.

it seems that any scripts i have on the new pages aren't being fired at all. in fact when i look into the source code of a page that has been updated(infinite scrolling) i cant see any of the 's.

i somehow need to load these three scripts again:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=***********";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.container').stickem();
    });
</script>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

im pretty new to javascript/jquery so any advice is welcome. thanks.

Comment: my question wasn't answered so i figured id elaborate more and post at a better time.

Comment: I'd suggest you to wait a week day to repost your question as user traffic (specially trusted users) is sensibily higher.

Comment: ok will do, that makes sense too. thank you.